# how to get the desired output using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

i have a table with records

```
create table rstbljobs  
(  
AutoID identity(1,1),  
AssignedToRstEmpID int,  
priorityid int,  
Jobstatusid int  
)


Insert into rstbljobs values ( 147,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 169,214,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 170,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 176,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 182,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 147,214,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 183,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 170,214,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 182,214,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 170,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 147,214,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 147,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 169,202,374)  
Insert into rstbljobs values ( 169,214,374)
```

i have another table UsersRSDesk

```
Create table UsersRSDesk  
(  
userid int,  
IsRecruit bit,  
status bit,  
noofhighprtjobs varchar(50)  
)
```

The records are

```
insert into UsersRSDesk values (147,1,0,null)  
insert into UsersRSDesk values (169,1,0,null)  
insert into UsersRSDesk values (170,1,0,null)  
insert into UsersRSDesk values (176,1,0,null)  
insert into UsersRSDesk values (182,1,0,null)  
insert into UsersRSDesk values (183,1,0,null)
```

The query is as follows:

```
select AssignedToRstEmpID,COUNT(AssignedToRstEmpID)as Noofcount from RStblJobs 
group by AssignedToRstEmpID
```

from the above query,i want the noofcount from rstbljobs to be inserted into usersrsdesk.noofhighprtjobs column.Whenever i update rstbljobs table then also the same count should be reflected here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you probably shouldn't. Storing calculated values is not normally good practise for an OLTP database (it would be very normal for OLAP), instead if this is a figure that you need to access regularly then you should consider creeating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.UserJobs
AS
    SELECT  AssignedToRstEmpID,
            Noofcount = COUNT(AssignedToRstEmpID) 
    FROM    RStblJobs 
    GROUP BY AssignedToRstEmpID;
```

You can then just use this view to get your count as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    UsersRSDesk
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UserJobs
            ON UserJobs.AssignedToRstEmpID = UsersRSDesk.userid;
```

If you expect this to be a performance drain then you could create an Indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.UserJobs
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  AssignedToRstEmpID,
            Noofcount = COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM    dbo.RStblJobs 
    GROUP BY AssignedToRstEmpID;

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_UserJobs_AssignedToRstEmpID 
  ON dbo.UserJobs (AssignedToRstEmpID);
```

With the indexed view the count will then be stored in the clustered index, but you will need to use the [NOEXPAND](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint to ensure the use of the index.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    UsersRSDesk
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UserJobs (NOEXPAND)
            ON UserJobs.AssignedToRstEmpID = UsersRSDesk.userid;
```

**[Example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9792e/2)**